# Facebook Open Graph image posts being cropped

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

One of our apps has been successfully posting images of completed jigsaw puzzles to a users Facebook Timeline for many months. These images filled the full width of available space within the Timeline as shown in the image below (before).

[image: Before]

Since some point early in 2015, Timeline posts now show as cropped, square images (after)

[image: After]

There have been no changes to the app, we've also loaded an older version of the app and this is producing the same results.

The image size that is being posted is 900px x 600px, we've tried changing this to 960px x 640px and one based on a ratio of 1.91:1, suggestions raised in other posts. Nothing has worked.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to force the full size image into a users Timeline without it being cropped..?

Comment: Are you using the og:image:width and og:image:height params in your story, as documented here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images.

Comment: No but the info at that link does show that Open Graph stories now post images as a fixed square format. This would appear to be something that has changed as we have Timeline posts with a larger oblong image. Looks like we've been chasing our tails trying to resolve something that is now a standard feature.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Facebook library (v4.2.0) downloaded from JCenter into Android Studio seems to fix the issue - we are now seeing full width images again on a users Timeline.